# Updating dataTable data after clicking on Search button

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, datatables, ajax4jsf

Once page `xyz.xhtml` gets loaded, I am displaying 10 records.

```
<h:dataTable var="c" value="#{userServiceBean.showTop10Applicant()}"
   styleClass="order-table"
   headerClass="order-table-header"
   rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
   border="1" id="appListDataTable" width="100%">
  <h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    Applicant Name
  </f:facet>
    #{c.displayName}
  </h:column>
</dataTable>
```

In `showTop10Applicant()` I'm returning 10 random records.

Above this dataTable, I have search textbox and search button. I have used ajax for checking the data.

```
<h:inputText id="searchApplicant" value="#{userDataBean.toSearch}" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;+&nbsp;&nbsp;
<h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{userServiceBean.searchApplicantsByCriteria()}">
    <f:ajax execute="searchApplicant"  render=":appListDataTable"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

In `searchApplicantsByCriteria()` I am displaying all records that I have (right now I am not checking for any criteria).

***BUT***, when ***I click on Search***, I get same 10 records back as earlier.

***Could anyone help where I am getting wrong.***

### Update 1

Below is what I want to do.

I want to search some persons that are there in database. When the page gets loaded, I am displaying random 10 persons using dataTable (using method `showTop10Applicant()`).

In Search textbox, I write abc and click on Search button. What I want is that the dataTable that is already present (where we are displaying 10 random records) get updated with the finding of abc. Lets say there are 2 person whose name contains abc,  then I should get only list of these two persons.

***Hope*** I am clear now. Let me know incase if there are any questions.

### Update 2

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:body>
    <ui:composition template="../layout/homeLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
        <center>
            <h2>
            <u>
                <h:outputText value="Manage Applicants"></h:outputText>
            </u>
            </h2>
        </center>
        <br />
        <h:form id="myForm002" prependId="false">

            <div align="right">
            <h:inputText id="searchApplicant" value="#{userDataBean.toSearch}" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;+&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{userDataBean.status}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="ALL" itemLabel="All" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="A" itemLabel="Active" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="IA" itemLabel="Inactive" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;

            <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{userServiceBean.searchApplicantsByCriteria()}">
                <f:ajax execute="searchApplicant"  render=":myForm001:appListDataTable"/>
            </h:commandButton>

            </div>
        </h:form>
        <hr width="100%"></hr>
        <br />

        <center>
            <h:form id="myForm001" prependId="false">    
            <f:metadata>
                <f:event listener="#{userServiceBean.showTop10Applicant()}" type="preRenderView" />
            </f:metadata>
            <h:dataTable var="c" value="#{userServiceBean.showTop10Applicant()}"
                     styleClass="order-table"
                     headerClass="order-table-header"
                     rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
                     border="1" id="appListDataTable" width="100%">
                <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Applicant Name
                </f:facet>
                #{c.displayName}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    User ID
                </f:facet>
                #{c.userId}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Email ID
                </f:facet>
                #{c.email}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Mobile Number
                </f:facet>
                #{c.contactReference}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Active?
                </f:facet>
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{c.isActive}"></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            <br />
            </h:form>
        </center>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not clear what "sending all records I have" means. What is the expected result? Could you add the bean code as well? Where is your form tag?

Comment: @MattHandy : Updated the question... Could you please check and let me know if you still have any questions...

Comment: are you sure that your searchApplicantsByCriteria() really modifies the list that is being returned by showTop10Applicant() ?

Comment: @MattHandy : yes, I am not sure why... :( I get same 10 records :(

Let me know if I need to post all xhtml file...

Comment: how about placing myForm002 content into  myForm001 (the myForm002 content is small so it wont do harm) and change <f:ajax execute="searchApplicant"  render=":myForm001:appListDataTable"/>
into <f:ajax execute="searchApplicant"  render="@form"/>

Comment: upon button click and searchApplicantsByCriteria() execute... are you sure that the method does modify the list that you r dataTable  relys on? any chance that its some temp local list?

Comment: @Daniel : At first I see all output in log file.. later datatable function also get called and list gets replaced... :(

Comment: have you tried removing the <f:metadata> <f:event... ?

Comment: yes, still same list with 10 records..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the datatable in a panelGroup like `<h:panelGroup id="dataTableGroup">` and then call `<f:ajax execute="searchApplicant"  render="dataTableGroup"/>`. This should work.

Comment: ah true, you need to use a panelGroup + use the absolute path as Matt described it above, like `<f:ajax execute="searchApplicant" render=":formId:dataTableGroup"/>`

Comment: you definitely should remove the <f:metadata> section + might wrap the h:datatable. and as other commenters mentioned, there might be errors in your backing bean. you should also list userServiceBean and userDataBean here.

Comment: and also remove the `prependId=false` attributes from the forms. you can use the default, which is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the wrong component. The ":" is the document root and you certainly have a form tag wrapped around your dataTable (that's why I asked for the form). So at least you should use something like this:

```
render=":formId:appListDataTable"
```

Replace `formId` with your real form id. This assumes that there are no other naming containers in between like `h:panelGroup` etc.

If both (the input field and the table) are inside the same naming container you could omit the colon:

```
render="appListDataTable"
```

Furthermore there might be other sources of error. I would suspect your backing bean methods (as commented by Daniel, that's why I asked for the bean code).

Comment: let me check. Get back to you asap

Comment: I have updated question (Update 2) with code. I am getting those 10 records only.

Comment: Ok you are using `prependId=false`. Look into the html source (in browser). What is the id of your datatable? What is the content of `userServiceBean.searchApplicantsByCriteria`

Comment: `userServiceBean.searchApplicantsByCriteria` will show me all records that I have (say 100 records as I have 100 records in my List)

Comment: In browser I have name as `myForm001` & `myForm002`.

Comment: I think the problem is that the scope that I have is `@RequestScoped`. I have changed to `@ViewScoped` and checking....